# Extracting columns from txt file with two delimiters using powershell

Tags: powershell, split, delimiter, txt

i have a sample.txt file

```
Processing...
Cl.Cog="/u/l/Cg.txt"
V.DM=Nv
AL.Ft="He Se Fe",Bt,@L(Ey,0),&Ct:&Cu3
```

i need to seperate this file with 4 different columns with new column added before
output.csv

```
PHP> This is hard coded line;

column1              column2             column3             column4              
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------
abcdefg                Cl                 Cog               "/u/l/Cg.txt"               
abcdefg                V                  DM                   Nv
abcdefg                AL                 Ft                 "He Se Fe",Bt,@L(Ey,0),&Ct:&Cu3
```

so for i have tried this,which doesn't seem to be working

```
Get-Content test.txt | 
$headerString = "PHP> This is hard coded line;"

$headerElements = $headerString -split "\s+" | Where-Object{$_}
$headerIndexes = $headerElements | ForEach-Object{$headerString.IndexOf($_)}
$results = $data 
Foreach {"$(($_ -split '\s+',4)[0..2])"} |
Out-file -filepath "D:\output.txt"
```

Comment: where does `abcdefg` comes from in your code? also you need to explain what is the column delimiter as your expected output and your code dont relate at all

Comment: its an extra column added before with same string (abcdefg) in that..and my code i am still working on that

Comment: This is not the right way of handling the data.  Can you post more of the txt file with more than one sample of the input.  One row of the CSV should contain multiple rows of the text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encourage you to not try and "build" the csv yourself. Focus on creating the objects you want and then simply export to csv. Your header line as more columns then your data, plus you don't state specifically you want to exclude the `processing...` line, nor do you account for it in your example code, but your desired output doesn't show it. Here is how I would handle what I believe you are after.

```
# Create the headers for the csv from your hard coded line
$headerString = "PHP> This is hard coded line;"
$headers = -split $headerString

# Get the text content, you can skip 1 here if you need to exclude processing
$data = Get-Content test.txt

# Iterate over each line replacing literal period and equals with a pipe. 
# Combine this with your static first column value and a pipe 
# I chose pipe as a delimiter as your text file had commas but not a pipe
$results = foreach($line in $data){
    # again, this will create a pipe delimited string
    $csv = 'abcdefg|' + ($line -replace '\.|=','|')
    # convert this string to csv with your custom headers
    $csv | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter '|' -Header $headers
}
```

All the output was collected in `$results`. You can review and/or export now

```
$results | Format-Table

PHP>    This is  hard                          coded line;
----    ---- --  ----                          ----- -----
abcdefg Cl   Cog /u/l/Cg|txt                              
abcdefg V    DM  Nv                                       
abcdefg AL   Ft  He Se Fe,Bt,@L(Ey,0),&Ct:&Cu3  

# output to csv
$results | Export-Csv Some.csv -NoType
```

If you want to output the table view to a text file (I don't recommend it, csv is much easier to consume again later) you can do this

```
$results | Format-Table | Out-String | Set-Content c:\temp\textfile.txt
```

Comment: i want to exclude processing and also..in output i am getting my desired table..how to export same table to txt file..i have tried out-file ..and export-csv...its not working

Comment: ' $data =Get-content 'output.txt' $data | foreach {$_.replace('","',' ').TrimStart('"').TrimEnd('"')}
$data | Export-Csv  -Path 'E:\new_1.txt' -NoType '

Comment: is the a way to give fixed width to each column in this format table text file..i have tried this..but it doesnt seem to be working '$a =  @{Expression={$_.Name};Label= "Application";width=21}, `
     @{Expression={$_.Name};Label="Database";width=20}, `
     @{Expression={$_.Name};Label="variable";width=20},
     @{Expression={$_.Name};Label="value";width=20}

 

$width = Get-Process | Format-Table -Property $a |Out-string | Set-Content c:\inal.txt' '

Answer (score -1):

Try following :

```
$inputFilename = 'c:\temp\test.txt'
$outputFilename = 'c:\temp\test.csv'
$contents = Get-Content $filename

$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach($row in $contents)
{
   if($row.Contains('='))
   {
      $newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject

      $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName column1 -NotePropertyValue 'abcdefg'
      $splitRow = $row.Split('=')
      $splitPeriod = $splitRow[0].Split('.')

      $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName column2 -NotePropertyValue $splitPeriod[0]
      $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName column3 -NotePropertyValue $splitPeriod[1]
      $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName column4 -NotePropertyValue $splitRow[1]

      $table.Add($newRow) | Out-Null
   }
}
$table
$table | export-csv -Path $outputFilename
```

Comment: Your answer is not only PowerShell-unidiomatic and therefore verbose, it is much slower than an idiomatic solution. Based on my benchmarks on a Windows 11 22H2  machine running Windows PowerShell 5.1 with 1,000 input lines, about 50(!) times slower. I invite you to run the benchmarks yourself (also to make sure that I'm measuring correctly): https://gist.github.com/mklement0/e8cabb620342af37ae7d0faecba7d588#file-bm_76011142-ps1

Comment: @mklement0 : The time difference is not the programming style.  It is the Add-Member that is slow.  Using $newRow = [pscustomobject] @{
          column1 = 'abcdefg'
          column2 = $splitPeriod[0]
          column3 = $splitPeriod[1]
          column4 = $splitRow[1]
        } makes my time and your about the same.

Comment: Yes, using repeated `Add-Member` calls when a single `[pscustomobject]` literal will do accounts for most of the slowdown. The other unidiomatic part is to manually build a list (which you inexplicably name `$table`), instead of using the `foreach` statement as an expression and letting PowerShell create an array for you. Both practices (whatever you want to call them - I didn't use the term "programming style") amount to code that is not only more verbose, but in this case significantly slower.

Comment: Direct use of .NET APIs, if used correctly, can offer performance _benefits_ (your use of `[System.Collections.ArrayList]` does the opposite), but idiomatic, high-level PowerShell code should always be tried first - there's no need to _start_ with .NET APIs, not just to avoid the verbosity and lower level of abstraction, but also to avoid needing knowledge from a _separate knowledge domain_.

Comment: To quote from [PowerShell scripting performance considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/performance/script-authoring-considerations): "Many of the techniques described here aren't idiomatic PowerShell and may reduce the readability of a PowerShell script. Script authors are advised to use idiomatic PowerShell unless performance dictates otherwise."

Comment: @mklement0 :I totally disagree with the READABILITY comment.  Code should easily be commented and putting everything into one long instruction doesn't allow comments and makes it very difficult to debug.

Comment: There is no need to place a pipeline on a single line, and dosing so should and can easily be avoided: just end each segment with `|` and continue on the next line, which also allows you to place comments both after and between pipeline segments. Script blocks in pipelines allow debugging, just like outside pipelines. Pipelines without script blocks rarely need debugging, and you can inspect intermediate results with `-OutVariable`, if needed.
More importantly, your argument is fundamentally specious: Advising against using a language's core features and commands is obviously self-defeating.