# Powershell save to copy and paste recursively

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I am working on a script that collects a lot of lines of data. The main thing bugging me is I want the `Name` to be copied after a string until it hits the next `Name` item and from then use that name to the next strings. I will turn this text file into a CSV and the rest of my script takes over from that. But I cannot do that until I can correctly comma deliniate this. The format I want is:

```
X,Y,Name
Lat,Lon,Red1
Lat,Lon,Red1
Lat,Lon,Red2
Lat,Lon,Red3
...
```

Currently I have my source text organized as:

```
Red1 
Lat,Lon
Lat,Lon
Red2
Lat,Lon
Red3
Lat,Lon
...
```

Due to my source text will change and usually involves more than 500 lines, I do not want to simply copy and paste it in CSV format, that is making me prompt the user to make the changes and then hit yes to proceed, I wish to make the script a click once and out comes the result.

I have tried to use something like this:

```
(Get-Content $Makron2\kmlPrep1.txt -Raw) -replace '<kml:name>(.*?)</kml:name>', '<kml:name>,,NameStart,$1</kml:name>' |Set-Variable -Name "NameX" -Value '$1' |Set-Content -path $Makron2\kmlPrep1.txt
```

I want what is in between the `<kml:name> </kml:name>`, save it as a variable, and then paste it after `Lat,Lon,$NameX`

```
(Get-Content $Makron2\kmlPrep2.txt) -replace '<kml:coordinates>','$NameX' | Set-Content -Path $Makron2\kmlChangeMe.txt
```

In the previous I have it replacing as well for another purpose, but I am wondering if its possible to save what is in the `(.*?)` and then recall it later rather just in this statement. the previous only returns `$1` instead of `Red1` or any other names.

But it's not working for me, as I am limited in how to grep things in PowerShell. I am mostly self taught in this.

Comment: It's still quite unclear after self-formatting it. Please show example of output(s) that you need.

Comment: I need for the output, to copy the Name is(Red) and place it after the Lat/Lon with a comma and the Name.

Comment: So, basically, what you are saying is that if a line contains no comma, it's a new name.  And if the line does contain a comma, it's a lat, lon pair and is to be used with the most recent name to generate a triplet for the output csv.  Is this correct?

Comment: @Rubric23 ok, that part is more or less clear. But why do you mention e.g. `<kml:name>`? That's nowhere to be found in the shown input/output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact requirements aren't clear, because your sample input doesn't match your solution attempt, but the problem seems to come down to this:

- When processing lines, you need to *maintain state*, namely by caching the most recent name, which is part of the value from a single-value line, in a variable.
- That variable can then be used in modifying the subsequent multi-value lines.

The [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement enables both stateful line-by-line processing as well as [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-matching of lines:

```bash
$( # Wrap the switch statement in $(...), so it can be used in a pipeline.

  switch -Regex -File $Makron2\kmlPrep2.txt {
    # A (new) name line -> store the relevant part in $name
    '<kml:name>(.*?)</kml:name>' { $name = $Matches.1 }
    # A multi-value line: use $name to augment it and implicitly output the result.
    default                      { "$_,$name" }
  }

) # | Set-Content ...
```

Note the use of the [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches) variable to refer to the results of the regex-matching operation (this variable is also populated when you use the [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) operator).

Enclosing the `switch` statement in `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--) allows it to participate in a pipeline.

- `$(...)` collects all output in memory first, which is the prerequisite for writing back results to the input file.
- If that is not needed and memory-friendly *streaming* processing is desired, use `& { ... }` instead, i.e. enclose the `switch` statement in a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) and invoke with `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-).

---

As for **what you tried**:

Fundamentally, your approach lacks stateful cross-line processing, but to address some aspects that are inherently broken:

- The `$1` placeholder is only meaningful inside the substitution operand of a [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operation, where it refers to the value of the 1st capture group in the regex.

  - Despite its appearance, it is *not* a PowerShell variable, and is unrelated to a PowerShell variable of that name.
- Therefore, your attempt to use `Set-Variable` with `$1` cannot work; moreover `'$1'` - due to use of `'...'` rather than `"..."` quoting - is a [*verbatim* string literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings) whose verbatim content is `$1` - no [string expansion (interpolation)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) is performed.
- [`Set-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Set-Variable) has *no output* (except if you add `-PassThru`), so using it as *input* to another command in the pipeline is pointless.

  - `Set-Variable` is rarely used in practice, because `$var = 'value'` is both more concise and efficient than `Set-Variable var 'value'` - though `$var = 'value'` requires an *expression* context, which inside a pipeline usually means use inside a script block (`{ ... }`) passed to [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/ForEach-Object) or, as shown above, in action blocks of `switch` statements.

Comment: This definately helped me! unfortantely, it adds extra lines at the end of the text for whatever reason, might be a result from earlier in the script. But this is the result i was looking for! Many thanks!

Comment: @Rubric23, glad to hear it; my pleasure. Not sure about the extra lines; may indeed be something unrelated to this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using double quotes instead of single quotes surrounding the $1.  Single quotes prevent the $1 from being evaluated, and instead it is treated as literal text.

Better yet, replace the entire Set-Value phrase with

```
$Name = $1
```

This is the usual way to copy a value from one variable to another.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need Regex.  Just test if line has a comma

```
$data = @"
Red1

Lat,Lon

Lat,Lon

Red2

Lat,Lon

Red3

Lat,Lon
"@

$reader = [System.IO.StringReader]::new($data);
$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new();
$location = '';

while(($line =$reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null)
{
   $line = $line.Trim();

   if($line.Length -gt 0)
   {
      if(-not $line.Contains(','))
      {
         $location = $line;
      }
      if($line.Contains(','))
      {
         $splitLine = $line.Split(',');
         $newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject;
         $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Location -NotePropertyValue $location; 
         $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName X -NotePropertyValue $splitline[0].Trim();
         $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Y -NotePropertyValue $splitline[1].Trim();
         $table.Add($newRow)  | Out-Null;
      }
   }
}
$table;
```

Results

```
Location X   Y
-------- -   -
Red1     Lat Lon
Red1     Lat Lon
Red2     Lat Lon
Red3     Lat Lon
```

Comment: While the requirements are a little fuzzy, the OP's own attempt shows an attempt to extract the value of an XML element using a regex, so looking just for `,` is not enough.
As previously discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75348106/45375) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76011282/45375), I am down-voting for unidiomatic PowerShell code that sets a bad example.

Comment: @mklement0 : The requirements are perfectly clear except for the fact some location have multiple LAT/LON.  The lines without the comma are the names of the location and the ones with commas are the ones with Latitude and Longitude values.