# Trying to convert XML file into CSV in PowerShell results in an error

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

Trying to run a PowerShell script, as follows, I am presented with the error message "**Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.**".

The script is -

```
[XML]$inputFile = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\Desktop\Temp - 01D\XML_Audit.xml'
$inputFile.website.ChildNodes | Export-Csv "C:\Users\Desktop\Temp - 01D\XML_Audit.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter:"|" -Encoding:UTF8
Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\Desktop\Temp - 01D\XML_Audit.csv'
```

The error is received at line number 2, where it says *Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.*

Executing the command - *Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\Desktop\Temp - 01D\XML_Audit.xml'*, results in the XML file being displayed.

I was expective the CSV file to be generated. Executing the command - *Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\Desktop\Temp - 01D\XML_Audit.xml'*, results in the XML file being displayed.

**UPDATE -**
The content of the XML file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!--Audit Doc...-->
<Document>
  <Row OptionId="Provider" AuditDateTime="10-Mar-2022 11:44:36 AM" AuditType="Update" UserId="abc123" Remark="Provider Updated " VersionSelected="">
    <Element ColumnName="ProviderId" ColumnValue="2088" />
    <Element ColumnName="ProviderName" ColumnValue="CIMS_ALE_Domestic_Monthly" />
    <Element ColumnName="ConnectionString" ColumnValue="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Repo\DataBase\2058\abc1.xlsx;&#xD;&#xA;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=No;IMEX=1';" />
    <Element ColumnName="ProviderType" ColumnValue="Excel" />
    <Element ColumnName="IsActive" ColumnValue="True" />
  </Row>
  <Row OptionId="Provider" AuditDateTime="10-Mar-2022 11:44:51 AM" AuditType="Update" UserId="abc810" Remark="Provider Updated " VersionSelected="">
    <Element ColumnName="ProviderId" ColumnValue="2087" />
    <Element ColumnName="ProviderName" ColumnValue="CIMS_ALE_Domestic_Quarterly" />
    <Element ColumnName="ConnectionString" ColumnValue="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Repo\DataBase\2057\abc1.xls;&#xD;&#xA;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=No;IMEX=1';" />
    <Element ColumnName="ProviderType" ColumnValue="Excel" />
    <Element ColumnName="IsActive" ColumnValue="True" />
  </Row>
</Document>
```

The CSV file would be as follows:
[CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrH90.png)

Comment: Sample data and expected results?

Comment: As an aside: `[xml] (Get-Content ...)` should be avoided, because `Get-Content` may misinterpret the character encoding of XML files. Use the `[xml]` type's `.Load()` method instead; e.g.: `($xmlDoc = [xml]::new()).Load((Convert-Path ./file.xml))` - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68087177/45375) for details.

Comment: Original post updated.

Comment: If `<Document>` is the root (document) node, it looks like all you need to do is `$inputFile.Document.ChildNodes`

Comment: Many thanks. This worked.

Answer (score -1):

Try following :

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$inputFilename = "c:\temp\test.xml"
$outputFilename = "c:\temp\test.csv"

$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)

$rows = $doc.Descendants("Row")

$table =  [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
foreach($row in $rows)
{
   $newRow = New-Object -TypeName pscustomobject
   foreach($att in $row.Attributes())
   {
      $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $att.Name.LocalName -NotePropertyValue $att.Value
   }
   foreach($element in $row.Elements())
   {
      $tempRow = $newRow | Select-Object -Property *
      $tempRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ColumnName" -NotePropertyValue $element.Attribute("ColumnName").Value 
      $tempRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ColumnValue" -NotePropertyValue $element.Attribute("ColumnValue").Value
      $table.Add($tempRow) | out-null
   }
}
$table | Export-CSV -path $outputFilename -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: As previously discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75348106/45375) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76011282/45375), I am down-voting for unidiomatic PowerShell code that sets a bad example. More fundamentally, offering a technologically unrelated solution without addressing the problem stated in the question and without explaining _why_ a different technology may be called for - if at all - is unhelpful.